# How do I set a project end date to be 6 months out from the start date?

Tags: apex, formula, date

I created a custom field called Start_Date of type date. I created another field called End_Date that I would like to default to Start_Date + 6 months. But whenever I try to do this in a formula I get the error: "Field Start_Date__c may not be used in this type of formula".

This is the formula I tried:

ADDMONTHS(Start_Date__c,6)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have same data type for the Formula field(End Date) as well, i.e., `Date`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both Start_Date__C and End_Date__c are date fields. Any other thoughts on what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated the same requirement on my Developer edition and it seems to be working as expected. 
What I have done:

1. **Start Date:**
   [image: startDateField]
2. **End Date:** This is of data type: **Formula** and return type: **Date**
   [image: EndDateField]
3. **Formula on End Date field:**
   [image: Formula]
4. **Test Case Record:**

   [image: Sample]

**Note:** Just make sure you/user profile have the necessary FLS for the field: `Start_Date__c` before trying to access it while creating the `End_Date__c` formula field. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that was my problem I had End Date set to data type Date.  I have one other issue now.  I would like this to be defaulted to the 6 months out, but I want to make the field user-editable.  Is this possible using a formula field or through another method?

Comment: Formula fields are auto-generated(based on criteria) and cannot be edited. So you might consider doing this: You might need to create one more field(lets say: `End_Date_Changeable__c`) to auto-populate(using a Workflow/Process builder) it's value from the above Formula field(`End_Date__c`).  Make sure your workflow should evaluate only at the "On Creation"

Comment: Yep it's working now.  Hid the formula field and the user is able to edit the End Date field that is visible.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The format for ADDMONTHS is correct. You most likely selected the wrong data type for the End_Date formula. Verify that the formula is data type date and not some other data type. Also, I pasted a link to salesforce documentation regarding formulas if you need a reference.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both Start_Date__C and End_Date__c are date fields. Any other thoughts on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Start_Date__c should be of field type Date.  The error message mentions the same.

Change the Field Type of Start_Date__c

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Both Start_Date__C and End_Date__c are date fields.  Any other thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: As confirmed by you, this was the issue.